# reading csv file with nifi-which processor can be used?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have the following task to do using NIFI - I have a csv file which has columns: first name, last name, date of birth, address, phone, mail. I need to read this file record by record and extract the first name, last name and date of birth from each record to use later to create a rest query. What processors are best to use for this task?

Comment: Do you want to split the record to FlowFiles and then split the content into attributes?

Comment: If it is possible, then use only selected attributes, then yes. I just need to go through this csv file row by row and extract the first name, last name and date of birth from each row and e.g. put it into the database

Comment: If you want only filter columns then use a `QueryRecord` processor (for instance `SELECT first_name, last_name, date_of_birth FROM FLOWFILE`)

Comment: I'm not talking about filtering, but about extracting the first name, last name and date of birth from each row to create a rest request from it

Comment: The "filtering" in this case I believe only refers to if you have other fields in the record but only want the ones you mention. If those are the only fields in the record you can use @tonykoval 's query or just `SELECT * from FLOWFILE`